# How to escape Newline in ECHO command with sql

Tags: sql-server, cmd, escaping, echo, xp-cmdshell

i have a Format file for exporting data from SQL Server to local hdd.
I have to create this Format file on the remote machine via SQL command.

```
Server srv = new Server(conn);    
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery("xp_cmdshell 'ECHO 10.0 1 1       SQLBINARY           8       0       \"\"   1     blob                 \"\">> " + destinationPathFormat + "'");
```

Without the Newline escaping the Format file is not valid and exporting the data isn't working.
The string has to be escaped here: 10.0 [ESCPAPE] 1 [ESCPAPE] 1

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `echo` appends a newline, you can issue multiple echo commands.

```
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(
    "xp_cmdshell 'ECHO line1 >> " + destinationPathFormat + "'");
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(
    "xp_cmdshell 'ECHO line2 >> " + destinationPathFormat + "'");
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(
    "xp_cmdshell 'ECHO line3 >> " + destinationPathFormat + "'");
```

You're already using `>>`, which appends to a file, instead of `>`, which creates a file.

Comment: That's strange.  You can try to escape characters with `^`, like `echo ^|`.  On my system that is not required for `1` though.